# Timer trigger in Durable Azure Functions

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have such initial azure function:

```
[FunctionName("TriggerNoResponseFunction")]
    public static async Task Run(
        [TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")] TimerInfo info,
        [OrchestrationClient] DurableOrchestrationClient starter)
```

My Orchestrator function:

```
[FunctionName("NoResponseOrchestrator")]
    public static async Task Run(
        [OrchestrationTrigger] DurableOrchestrationContext context,
        ILogger log)
```

And an activity trigger:

```
[FunctionName("NoResponseHandlerFunction")]
    public static void Run(
        [ActivityTrigger] DbReadOptions readOptions)
```

But in this case my Activity trigger function gets called a lot of times intead of CRON expression which as i understand should restrict count of callings. What i'm doing wrong. How to achieve durable function to get called only by timer schedule?
Thanks for help in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "a lot of times"? How frequently? Your cron expression is every minute, is that what you want?

Comment: @RuiJarimba Sctivity trigger gets calling one by on enot every minute at all. I can't see the point what cause that behaviour